# Count the number of files with identical names but different timestamps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to calculate the number of files that have the same filename but different timestamp in pandas dataframe.

Example:

```
df:

filename                       count
phd_20193_lab_sens.txt.gz       100
phd_20194_lab_sens.txt.gz        50 
phd_20198_lab_sens.txt.gz       300 
phd_20199_lab_sens.txt.gz       200
```

Output:

```
df_final

filename                count
phd_lab_sens.txt.gz     650
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df.filename = df.filename.str.replace('(\d+_)', '', regex=True)
# df.filename = df.filename.str.replace('(\d{5}_)', '', regex=True)
df_final = df.groupby('filename', as_index=False).sum()
```

OUTPUT:

```
              filename  count
0  phd_lab_sens.txt.gz    650
```